# SQL Express 2005 to SQL 2008 Workgroup for Sharepoint WSS 3.0

Tags: sql, sharepoint, migration

I am trying to migrate sharepoint wss 3.0 databases from SQL Express 2005 to SQL 2008 Workgroup edition.

I have backed up the database, but not sure how to best attached/restore them to the new version and get up and running again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend. And TechNet.

See [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288664(office.12).aspx) for instance.